# Iterating through a vector and using that value as column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I am using this for loop to standardize the data in my columns. Here m_sel_cols is a vector with column names.

```
for(i in m_sel_cols)
    {
        cal <- work_data1$i
        cal <- ((cal-mean(cal))/sd(cal))
    }
```

Suppose if my column name is "A" then is you do :

```
  ...
        cal <- work_data1$A
  ...
```

The number of columns in my dataset is huge and I want to convert it back to data frame, I know `cbind()` can be used but how within the `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "loop" through columns using `sapply`.

```
xy <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
sapply(xy, FUN = function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x))

      a  b  c
[1,] -1 -1 -1
[2,]  0  0  0
[3,]  1  1  1
```

or

```
> scale(xy)
      a  b  c
[1,] -1 -1 -1
[2,]  0  0  0
[3,]  1  1  1
attr(,"scaled:center")
a b c 
2 5 8 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
a b c 
1 1 1
```

Comment: I haven't seen your `scale`.  Is that updated answer?

Comment: @akrun yupp, your answer appeared when I reloaded the page after the update.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
xy %>%
     mutate_all(scale)
#   a  b  c
#1 -1 -1 -1
#2  0  0  0
#3  1  1  1
```

#### data

```
xy <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
```